# Directsound: how to create a secondary buffer using SecondaryBuffer(Stream,BufferDescription,Device) constructor?

Tags: c#, directx, directsound

I'm trying to create a static secondary buffer which receives sound data from an array not from a file. so i want to use the `SecondaryBuffer(Stream,BufferDescription,Device)` constructor but i don't know how to do that. can anybody show me an example in c#?